# Environment variable as date STRING?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

$ date --version
    date (GNU coreutils) 8.25

When I pass a quoted string into date, the translation to epoch works fine, but when the quoted string is in an environment variable, no joy.

```
$ date --date "09/25/2016 12:31:52 AM" +%s
1474781512

$ echo $LAT
"09/25/2016 12:31:52 AM"

$ date --date $LAT +%s
date: extra operand ‘AM"’

$ date --date "$LAT" +%s
date: invalid date ‘"09/25/2016 12:31:52 AM"’

$ date --date '$LAT' +%s
date: invalid date ‘$LAT’
```

What am I doing wrong?  (This isn't homework.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have literal double quotes around the expanded variable (`$LAT`) value.

Either remove the double quotes at the time of declaration or use parameter expansion to remove at runtime:

```
date --date "${LAT//\"/}" '+%s'
```

Comment: The (unshown) source of LAT put in the double quotes.  Removing them at run-time did the trick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes in your variable and that is causing the issues. You can see it here:

```
$ echo $LAT
"09/25/2016 12:31:52 AM"
```

If your variable had just the date it wouldn't show the quotes.

Comment: The source of the LAT has the double-quotes.